# Micronaut: Как собрать метрики в формате Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

Как настроить Micronaut для получения `/metrics` в формате Prometheus?

Используется: micronaut 1.0.0.M3

Сейчас:

```
micronaut:
...
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
```

результат: список наименований метрик

```
{"names":["jvm.memory.max","executor.pool.size"...]}
```

Мне нужно получить метрики в формате([formats](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/)) для Prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент решили проблему так.

1. Добавить новый эндпоинт. Или создать контролер с мапингом на `/metrics`;
2. Эндпоинт возвращает `scrape()`;
3. Замапить эндпоинт на `/prometheus`(новый эндпоинт не удается замапить на `/metrics`);
4. Отключить дефолтный эндпоинт на `/metrics`.

Config:

```
micronaut:   
  ...   
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true 
... 
endpoints:
...
  metrics:
    enabled: false
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
```